# A question about the rationality of Hurwitz Zeta functions.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, sieve-theory, dirichlet-series

I'm checking over some of my work from studying prime numbers, and I found where I used the Hurwitz Zeta function $$\zeta(s,\alpha)_{\alpha \in [0,1)} = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^s},  $$
to represent the sum of the inverses of integers in a specific residue class

If we let $\alpha \in [0,1) \cap {\mathbb{Q}} $, then $\exists a < q : \alpha := \frac{a}{q}$ and if we let $T$ be the residue class $\{ a \pmod{q}\}$ we could form the sum 
$$ \sum_{n\in T} \frac{1}{n^s} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{\frac{1}{(qn+a)^s}} = \frac{1}{q^s}\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\frac{1}{(n + \alpha)^s}} = \frac{1}{q^s} \zeta(s,\alpha). $$

Is the sum irrational in general for all residue classes $T$, when $Re(s) > 1$?

Comment: How do you define $\zeta(1,\alpha)?$ Standard definition (e.g. https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#v) implies a simple pole at $s=1.$

Comment: And the simple pole is infinite, so neither rational nor irrational, right?

Comment: For $a \in (0,1)$ : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+a)^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \lfloor x-a \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx= \frac{s}{s-1}-a +s 
 \int_1^\infty (\lfloor x-a \rfloor-(x-a)) x^{-s-1}dx$ which is the analytic continuation to $\Re(s) > 0$

Comment: I'm not able to assume $a \in (0,1)$

Comment: I should say $|a| \in [0,1)$